# How to set drawn Bitmap width and height

Tags: android, bitmap

Please, I want to set size of my bitmap image. I searched it from stackover flow but I don't get it, I am dull.

```
public class Circle extends View{
float y=300 ;


public Circle(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
protected void  onDraw(Canvas c){
    super.onDraw(c);

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    c.drawBitmap(myBitmap,y,0,null);
    Bitmap myBitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),    R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    c.drawBitmap(myBitmap,y+100,0,null);
    invalidate();
}
}
```

It appears the original size of the image but I want it to change upon different screen size. I already know how to change it upon different screens but I don't know yet is how to set bitmap size. (I am using API min-10) . Please Advice me !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to scale it:

```
mBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);
```

Comment: you welcome, consider accepting the answer to help others too;-)